# JSON gives me back null

Tags: php, android, json

need help in this query any one can correct it for me he JSON gives me null
and dose not parse any thing to android app it prints the values i need when test it in neteans but do not parse the values to the android

```
<?php


    $nme = (isset($_REQUEST['place_name']) ? $_REQUEST['place_name'] : null);

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

    $db=mysql_select_db("around2",$con);

    $result=mysql_query("ٍٍٍٍٍٍSelect 
    historical_places.city_code , historical_places.address, historical_places.information, historical_places.place_code
    ,image.image_serial ,image.images
    ,videos.video_serial ,videos.video_url
    FROM historical_places 
    INNER JOIN image 
    ON image.place_code=historical_places.place_code 
    INNER JOIN videos 
    ON videos.place_code=historical_places.place_code 
    WHERE historical_places.place_name='$nme'");


    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    $output[]=$row; 
    } 

    print(json_encode($output)); 
    mysql_close(); 
    ?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here.. or how it relates to android. What do you mean when you say 'parse the values to the android'?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how this question relates to android, but this can't be right:

```
"ٍٍٍٍSelect
```